# Overflow error in VBA involving two integers and a Long Integer

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I don't code in VBA, but I need to debug a code written in it. When I run the code, I get an Overflow error, which I looked at online. I used breakpoints in the debugger to find the line of code that is giving me the error.

This is the line:

```
lngInt = nIntA * nIntB
```

The debugger says that nIntA (an integer) = 4,851, nIntB (another integer) = 10. lngInt is a long integer, if I'm reading this line correctly:

```
dim lngInt As Long
```

nIntA and nIntB are initialized with:

```
Public nIntA As Integer 
Public nIntB As Integer
```

If it helps, both are set from an Access form.

Nothing about this seems like it should be giving me an issue, so I'm assuming it's a quirk in VBA. What could be causing the error?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `Integer * Integer` gives `Integer`, so `4851 * 10` gives `Overflow` before it implicitly converts it to a `Long` to store in `lngInt`.  Use `lngInt = CLng(nIntA) * CLng(nIntB)`

Comment: or simply change the declarations`Public nIntA As Long` and
`Public nIntB As Long`

Comment: In any case your 16-bit `Integer` variables are internally being computed on 32-bit just like `Long` integers, so why not declare them `As Long` anyway? It's not a "VBA quirk", it's just how expression assignment works: the expression needs to get evaluated before its result can be assigned, and `Integer * Integer` is going to be `Integer`. Don't blame the language, VBA has far fewer "quirks" than people think - in any case it's much less flaky than, say, JavaScript math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Integer` type is obsolete. You can declare and use a 16-bit integer all you want, and the VBA runtime will enforce its limits, but internally it's (silently) converted to a 32-bit integer anyway, so why not just use `Long` (32-bit) integers in the first place?

That said, this has nothing to do with a "VBA quirk", and everything to do with the basics:

```
foo = [expression]
```

Before the runtime can perform the assignment of `foo`, the `[expression]` needs to be evaluated. The "quirk" is that VBA doesn't care about the type of `foo` until *after* the `[expression]` is evaluated, because it's going to have to (implicitly) convert it to that type anyway:

```
Dim foo As Double
foo = 2 + 2
```

Should `2 + 2` evaluate to a `Double` on its own? It doesn't, and doesn't need to either. `2 + 2` evaluates to `4`, and since both operands are `Integer`, the result will be an `Integer` and so the assignment will be:

```
Dim foo As Double
foo = CDbl((2 + 2))
```

Now if you have two `Integer` values multiplied together, and that the total overflows the type, per the specs you get that *overflow* error.

```
Dim foo As Long
foo = 32000 * 2
```

Because that's still:

```
Dim foo As Long
foo = CLng((32000 * 2))
```

Notice the inner parentheses: `(32000 * 2)` is evaluated as an `Integer` *before* the result can be converted to a `Long` and the result of that conversion assigned to `foo`.

If one of the operands were a `Long`, the result would be a `Long` - because both operands are `Integer`, the result will be `Integer`.

---

If you want funky expressions and mind-boggling implicit conversions, try Javascript. VBA isn't being "quirky" at all here.

Comment: @YowE3K [MSDN states it rather plainly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164506(v=office.10).aspx) - see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/1188513) on the subject.

Comment: So is what you're saying is that I should declare the two IntA and IntB as Long integers so that their product doesn't cause the overflow?

Comment: @JoubertLucas an expression will evaluate to the widest type used by its operands, so one of the two needs to be a long for the expression to evaluate to a long, yes.